# Density button to use a new volume calculation (black boxes) that takes the Total Gross Weight multiplied by the density of the syrup in CSI

Tags: button, process, formula, ido, csi

I need to add the Density button to use a new volume calculation (black boxes) that takes the Total Gross Weight multiplied by the density of the syrup in CSI.

Tried to get the code done but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
Dim IDOResponseData As LoadCollectionResponseData
                IDOResponseData = Me.IDOClient.LoadCollection("ICSLPMFItemBase", "Wipitem", strFilter, "", 1)
                If IDOResponseData.Items.Count > 0 Then
                    strCustPart = IDOResponseData.Item(0, "WipItem").Value
                        ThisForm.Variables("ue_vCustPart").Value = strCustPart
```